# Windows 10 installation date is april while my computer is 2 days old :\

Tags: windows

I bought a new computer and the seller installed windows 10 on it (I paid for extra for it).

The first thing I've noticed is that Chrome was already installed in the computer.
I asked the seller and he replied that he installed the OS from an image file and that's why Chrome browser is there.

I then check the first installation date of the OS using cmd-->systeminfo and the the date that showed up is April 2016. I bought the computer on November 2nd 2016 and the whole thing just doesn't add up.

My question is, is it possible that installing the OS from an image file caused the date to be off, or I just bought a used computer for the price of a new one?
Thanks

Comment: determine if the machine was syspreped... open regedit and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup` if you see a value named `CloneTag` then the machine has been syspreped.

Comment: Is it an OEM licence?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is it possible that installing the OS from an image file caused the date to be off,

Yes (depending on exactly how they created/cloned the image).  If they made the master install image in April and have bene cloning since, then the install date will be the date the original OS was installed to make the master image from.